# What is the single most effective thing you have done to improve your soft skills?

Tags: communication

The single most effective thing I have done to improve my soft skills is to take an acting class.

What is the single most effective thing you have done to improve your soft skills?

Related questions:

- [What is the single most effective
  thing that you have done to improve
  your programming skills?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76364/what-is-the-single-most-effective-thing-you-did-to-improve-your-programming-skill)
- [Advice
  to improve programmer communication
  skills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96879/advice-to-improve-programmer-communication-skills)

Comment: This should be a community wiki.

Comment: No, it should be closed as not programming related - CW is not an "anything goes" option.

Comment: Disagree. Soft skills are definitely related to being a good developer.

Comment: I am new to SO.  How do I make it a community wiki?  What is the decision criteria for making something a CW vice a normal question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow

Comment: And if you read the criteria, it is obvious that it should not be cw and not closed

Answer (score 3):

Better appreciating just quite how dumb I really am.

Starting from the perspective of assuming that you're misunderstanding what's going on helps a lot.

Comment: +1 ... Just what I would have said, had I not said ... what I said.

Answer (score 2):

Started answering questions here - the ability to explain complex things in a way other people can understand them is very useful.

Comment: I disagree, answering a question from the safety of your keyboard isn't soft skills, for most developers, that's the centre of your comfort zone.

Comment: Reasonable, but pressure from not being shielded by the keyboard is not the only problem. Just being able to quickly provide a useful and easy to understand answer is a problem anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Not to be a smart-arse. People don't like smart-arses.

If you think you are right and everyone else is sure you are wrong, just agree and continue being right. Trying to argue it out just results in a negative outcome when people are not open to persuasion or are being stubborn.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to improve your soft skills is to *use* your soft skills. Put on a lunch time seminar for your fellow work mates. Nothing too scary, just pick a technology that you think could be introduced in house to make things work more efficiently, put together a five minute presentation and set some time aside for questions and discussion afterwards. You might even start a trend, one day a week a different person can talk about something that interests them.

Answer (score 2):

It's a tie between volunteering as newsletter editor for a local artists' group, and joining a small local theatrical dance group.

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago I attended a workshop about communication. And one thing that I learned there and I will never forget was: Try to understand why people act as they act, try to understand their motivation doing things as they do. That helped me a lot, especially in managing the management...

Comment: What was the name / provider of the workshop?

Comment: Kommunikation und Führung von Dagmar Ruppert

Answer (score 1):

I took a teaching course and have been doing a lot of teaching.

Answer (score 1):

Where I work currently has some material about improving one's Emotional Intelligence which is something that has been quite beneficial for me as it helps demystify some of how the world works.

In terms of not learning something, working on making small talk and being a bit more laid back has also improved my skills as not everyone wants every little thing analyzed to death and beyond.